# odd output when using multiple classes

Tags: java, arrays, object, output

I am very new with java programming and I am close to finishing a very big project for me. I am trying to make an employee registry that simply relays information back. Whenever I enter the info it just returns stuff like Name@5a965654. My classes are below and any help would be appreciated.

Main:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of employees to enter.");
        int employeeCount = Input.nextInt();
        Input.nextLine();

        Employee employees[] = new Employee[employeeCount];

        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String street;
        String city;
        String state;
        String zipCode;
        String monthHired;
        String dateHired;
        String yearHired;
        int employeeID;

        for(int x = 0; x < employeeCount; x++)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter the first name of employee " + (x + 1));
            firstName = Input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the last name of employee " + (x + 1));
            lastName = Input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the street of employee " + (x + 1));
            street = Input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the city of employee " + (x + 1));
            city = Input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the state of employee " + (x + 1));
            state = Input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the zip code of employee " + (x + 1));
            zipCode = Input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the month hired for employee " + (x + 1));
            monthHired = Input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the date hired for employee " + (x + 1));
            dateHired = Input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the year hired for employee " + (x + 1));
            yearHired = Input.nextLine();
            Name name = new Name(firstName, lastName);
            name.setName(firstName, lastName);
            Address address = new Address(street, city, state, zipCode);
            DateOfHire hireDate = new DateOfHire(monthHired, dateHired, yearHired);
            employees[x] = new Employee(name, address, hireDate, x);
        }

        for(int x = 0; x < employeeCount; x++)
        {
            employees[x].printInfo(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Employee class:

```
public class Employee 
{
    private Name name;
    private Address address;
    private DateOfHire hireDate;
    int ID;

    public Employee()
    {

    }

    public Employee(Name name, Address address, DateOfHire hireDate, int x)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.hireDate = hireDate;
        this.ID = x;
    }

    public void printInfo(int x)
    {
        System.out.println("Employee-" + (x + 1));
        System.out.println("Name: " + this.name);
        System.out.println("Address: " + this.address);
        System.out.println("Date of Hire: " + this.hireDate);
    }
}
```

Format of Name, DateHired, and Address classes:

```
public class Name 
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Name()
    {

    }

    public Name(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setName(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: PS when declaring many variables that are string you can do something like String name, surname, dob, address etc; instead of writing every variable in separate line

Answer (score 2):

A `Name` is not the same as a `String`, so when you print `this.name` in `Employee.printInfo`, it prints `Name@[numbers]`, indicating that what you're printing is a `Name` object at the location described by the numbers.

Try replacing that line with

```
System.out.println("Name: " + this.name.getName());
```

Also, you'll need to do something similar for the `Address` and `DateOfHire`, but I don't know what you have implemented for those, so I can't really say what specifically to do. Essentially, though, you'll need a method that gives a string representation of whatever object it is that you want to print.

Answer (score 1):

All classes in Java extend from the `java.lang.Object` which has a method `toString()`. This method is implemented as

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Whenever you call

```
System.out.println("Name: " + this.name);
```

String concatenation is done by implicitly calling the `toString()` method of your instance. If your class doesn't implement (override) the `toString()` method, then `Object`'s implementation is used.

[See the String Conversion rules in the Java Language Specification.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11)

> Otherwise, the conversion is performed as if by an invocation of the
>   toString method of the referenced object with no arguments; but if the
>   result of invoking the toString method is null, then the string "null"
>   is used instead.

Since your `Name` class does not have a `toString()` method, then its parent class' method is called, ie. `Object#toString()` and you get the output you see.

You should override the `toString()` method in all your classes. For example,

```
public class Name 
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Name()
    {

    }

    public Name(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setName(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

It does not matter than `toString()` and `getName()` return the same thing in this case. You have to follow the language spec.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement String toString()  method if you wanna print an object